# Holomorphic line bundle trivial outside a divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $D\subset X$ a divisor, $L$ a holomorphic line bundle over $X$. Suppose that $L$ is trivial on $X\setminus\operatorname{Supp} D$, then is it true that $L\cong \mathscr{O}(R)$ for some divisor $R$ with support in $\operatorname{Supp}D$?

Comment: In the complex-analytic setting, this is not true, even when $X$ has dimension $1$, since every line bundle on a Stein manifold of dimension $1$ is trivial by the exponential exact sequence. It's OK in the algebraic setting.

Comment: sorry, I don’t understand, what kind of $D$ and $L$ you take in this case of a stein manifold? Moreover, how about the case that $X$ is compact?

Comment: $X$ is compact (say, an elliptic curve), $D$ is a point, so $X\setminus\operatorname{Supp} D$ is a Stein manifold, and thus every $L$ is trivial on it. But not every $L$ can be written as $\mathcal O(R)$ with $R$ supported on the fixed point.

Comment: Ah! thanks a lot.